# JqGrid features question

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using this Jquery plug-in
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

How do you:

- edit the cell content (looking at
        the demo at
        http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
        doesn't work). Not sure if editing a
        cell is possible.
- hide rows

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing a cell is indeed possible.

For e.g. I have a row defined as

```
{name:'Weather', index:'weather', width:150, align:'center', editable:true, edittype:"select", editoptions: {value: "--:Unknown;-1:Rainy;1:Sunny;100:Cloudy;0:Clear"}},
```

There're methods in jqgrid like saveCell and editCell you can also call. For more information, see this:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing

Comment: I am guessing that the row may be hidden by using a simple Jquery method? as in $("#rowId").hide()..thanks!

Comment: yea, I did something like that for a project using jqgrid before. cheers :)